# Create a ton of plots in R via a loop

Tags: r, loops

I'm a Stata power user and R newbie having trouble getting loops to work properly in R. Basically I have a bunch of columns in a dataframe that I want to create a series of `pirateplots` with.

I tried

```
mycols <- c("column1","column2","column3")
for (i in mycols){
  filename <- paste("~/Desktop/",i,".pdf",sep="")
  pdf(filename)
  pirateplot(formula = i ~ xvar,
             data = df)
  dev.off()
}
```

and have also tried replacing `c("column1","column2","column3")` with the actual column names, i.e. `c(column1,column2,column3)` but that doesn't work either. Is there not a simple way to refer to an item in a list? It seems like R treats strings and variable names as different things, reasonably, but I can't seem to find documentation for how to deal with this exceedingly simple case.

In Stata this would be far simpler, something like

```
foreach v of varlist column1-column3 {
   loc filename = "`v'plot"
   scatter `v' xvar, name("`filename'")
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code will work if the entire formula is entered as a single string, which can be created using `paste`. Here's a reproducible example with the built-in `mtcars` data frame:

```
library(yarrr)

mycols <- c("wt","vs","hp")

for (i in mycols){

  filename <- paste(i, ".pdf", sep="")

  pdf(filename)
  pirateplot(formula = paste(i, "~ mpg"), data = mtcars)
  dev.off()
}
```

You code is producing a formula like the following each time through the loop:

```
pirateplot("column1" ~ xvar, data=df)
```

which is equivalent to the following in my example:

```
pirateplot("wt" ~ mpg, data=mtcars)
```

These generate this error:

> ```
> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
>   invalid term in model formula
> ```

The formula needs to be either of class formula, like `wt ~ mpg` using bare column names, or a string, like `"wt ~ mpg"`, which can be converted to a formula.

Comment: Thanks for this info, it works great. As a general thing for me to know, is it the case that the strategy "enter all of thing X as a string" usually works for this kind of issue? It didn't even occur to me to try that, since in Stata formulae and strings don't play nice together.

Comment: AFAIK, yes, though I can't guarantee there aren't exceptions. For example: `lm("mpg ~ wt + hp", data=mtcars)` instead of `lm(mpg ~ wt + hp, data=mtcars)` or `ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() + facet_grid("vs ~ am")` instead of `facet_grid(vs ~ am)`. In either case, you'd use the unquoted formula for a single model or plot. But the option of using a string let's you build up formulas for multiple models or plots programmatically using `paste`, instead of having to type out explicit formulas for each case.

Comment: FYI, strings can also be converted to formulas. See the help for the functions `formula` and `as.formula`.

Comment: And, just for convenience, you could use `paste0(...)` instead of `paste(..., sep = ””)`.